# How do I JS escape a template in Golang

Tags: go

I have a template and I want to JS escape the output to inject into another template. I could use template.JSEscape to do this after I've executed the template but it would seem more efficient to do it in one step, within a template.

I'd like to do something like...

```
var x = "{{js}}...some other template...{{end}}"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: "Is this possible?" No.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want to do. Can you show an example?

Comment: Maybe your js contains `{{xxx}}`?